# Alignment issues in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, jsp

I’ve the following lines in my code,

```
<TD id=“avail_1” style=“display:none;availability:hidden”>UrgentAvail</TD>
<TD id=“avail1_1” style=“display:none;availability:hidden”>substitutedBy</TD>
```

When I run the application on IE the above gets correctly displayed, but while running in chrome the alignment is not proper.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You should add some code so we can see if we can figure out the problem

Comment: You have curly quotes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly quotes might be giving this problem, replace them as belows..

```
<TD id="avail_1" style="display:none;availability:hidden">UrgentAvail</TD>
<TD id="avail1_1" style="display:none;availability:hidden">substitutedBy</TD>
```

And also plz share complete code if issue is not fixed.